# Getting information out of an online database

Tags: database

Is it possible to export the information in a public online directory (the list of CFA charterholders, for example: https://www.cfainstitute.org/community/membership/directory/pages/index.aspx#section-1)? I have very little background in computer science, so I don't even know if it's possible, but I enjoy learning. If it's possible, I'll try to do some more reading to figure out how to do it. Any pointers for important things to learn along these lines would be appreciated.

Is this considered hacking? It's public information, which makes me think it's not. But it's given out in spoon sized doses, so that makes me think that it is. If this is hacking, please let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about a programming problem

Comment: The underlying question is, How do you write a program to get all of the information in an online directory into a spreadsheet?

Comment: the concept is called [web-]scraping. You write this program by writing code to send http requests and handling the responses.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: nah, but you can upvote it.